# Ubuntu Text Ticker (Scrolling text)

Tags: application-development, desktop-environments, scrolling

Is there any application to display scrolling text on top of all windows in Ubuntu?
Something like **Tickr**, but what I want is an application that can display my own text, something like

```
appname "my own text"
```

then "my own text" is scrolling around the desktop. Can Tickr do that instead of RSS feed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the following into an .xml file and run `tickr <filename>.xml`, then you'll have what you want:

```
<rss version="0.91">
<channel>
<title>askubuntu.com is rad!</title>
</channel>
</rss>
```

You could then have the behavior you want (i.e., running `appname "my own text"`) by writing a script. For example, put the following into a file called `my-tickr.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash`
echo "<rss version="0.91">" > .tmp.tickr
echo "<channel>" >> .tmp.tickr
echo "<title> $1 </title>" >>.tmp.tickr
echo "</channel>" >>.tmp.tickr
echo "</rss>" >>.tmp.tickr

tickr .tmp.tickr &
```

Then run `chmod +x my-tickr.sh` to make the script executable. Then running `./my-tickr.sh 'askubuntu is rad!'` should behave as desired. Note the use of single quotes around 'askubuntu is rad!': this ensures that each character in your string is interpreted literally (Thanks to January for pointing this out).

Comment: Use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`), and the exclamation problem will go away (bash interprets some portions of a string in double quotes, so for example in "blah $a" the $a will get replaced by the contents of the variable `a`.

Answer (score 3):

(Some extra info.)

You can just type:

```
tickr FILE_NAME
```

In that case, the file will be processed as a simple text file, *not* as an XML one.

In settings, you can also *enable special characters* and then define one character for "tab" (eight spaces) and another one for "new page" (one empty line).

Or, with (for instance) `"new page" = '#' and "tab" = "%"`, you can just type:

```
tickr -specialchars=y -newpgchar=# -tabchar=% FILE_NAME
```

To see how it works, try with `FILE_NAME`:

```
hello hello
%
hello hello
#
hello
%
hello
%
hello
%
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Just re-reading my previous answer, I think I quite missed the real question. So, sorry for the mess. Now, I'm just making an alternative version of `my_tickr.sh` by dxvxd.

`my-tickr2.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
tmp_file="$(pwd)/.tmp.tickr"
echo "$1" > "$tmp_file"
tickr "$tmp_file" &
```

(Tickr can actually read non-xml / non-rss text files directly but it needs an absolute path.)

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your previous answer and add this answer content too in that.